# SQL select max value of varchar

Tags: sql, oracle, select, type-conversion, varchar

I have a varchar column that contains data like '0 03-03-14', '1 04-03-14' and so on.
I need to select the maximum one, in that case '1 04-03-14'.

My problem is that I can have the '1' (the max value) but how do I have to do if I also want the date ?

For now, I have this :

```
SELECT MAX(TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(revision, 1, INSTR(revision, ' ')-1)))
    FROM table
    WHERE name = 'aname'
        AND t_name = 'tname'
    GROUP BY revision
```

Does anyone have an idea ?

Thanks

Comment: You mean last date? 'max' how? '2 04-03-13' > '1 04-03-14' ?

Comment: that's what happens when people try to store 2 different data in the same column :-)

Comment: `SUBSTR(REPLACE(revision, '-', ''),2)` - this will give you varchar date

`TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(REPLACE(revision, '-', ''),2))` -  - this will give you number date

Comment: Why are you grouping by the field that you're splitting up?

Comment: So, you have a string field with a numeric value and a date/time value concatenated using a whitespace, and then you want to separate them in your query? There are ways to do it, but be aware performance is going to be *terrible* - you'd better separate that field in 2 and index them, at least in an materialized view if you don't want to touch your original table.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want  something like max(version, date version), try this:

```
Select * from (
  Select * from (
    SELECT
        TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(revision, 1, INSTR(revision, ' ')-1)) as rev
      , TO_DATE(SUBSTR(revision, 1, INSTR(revision, ' ')+1),'DD-MM-YY') as revDate
    FROM table
    WHERE name = 'aname'
    AND t_name = 'tname'
  ) extracted
  order by extracted.revDate, extracted.rev desc
) where rownum = 1
```

Comment: I agree, but it's effect terrible column data approach ;) I didn't know you can split this column - so answer is adequate.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

```
select max(revision)
from table
where name = 'aname' and t_name = 'tname';
```

It seems strange to put the revision number and date in one column.  Is that really your data format?  If not, modify your question with the actual data format.

Comment: Unfortunatly with this, I will have:
    `1 03-03-14
    10 03-03-14
    9 03-03-14`
Or 9 is lower than 10 ;)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your answers, I think the best solution would be to split those two parts :)